# Run a TCL script from matlab

Tags: matlab, tcl, environment-variables

I'm looking to run a TCL script within matlab directly.
My issue is that I'm using an Hydrological model called ParFlow. and therefore I need to load the libraries:

```
lappend auto_path $env(PARFLOW_DIR)/bin
package require parflow
namespace import Parflow::*
```

But when I run `unix('tclsh Run.tcl')` on matlab I have problem with `$env(PARFLOW_DIR)`:

```
no such variable
    (read trace on "env(PARFLOW_DIR)")
    invoked from within
"lappend auto_path $env(PARFLOW_DIR)/bin "
    (file "Run.tcl" line 6)
```

I tried to put using direct path to the bin like this:

```
lappend auto_path /home/raphael/parflow/parflow/bin
```

But then I get another error:

```
error reading package index file /home/raphael/parflow/parflow/bin/pkgIndex.tcl: can't read "::env(PARFLOW_DIR)": no such variable
```

Is there a way to define `$env(PARFLOW_DIR)` ? I don't really understand how it load the libraries or how it works ?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `env` array holds the environment variables for the process. These may be set either during the running of the program (by writing to that array) or prior to starting the process running *by whatever mechanism is used for setting environment variables*. In Matlab, you use [`setenv`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html):

```
setenv('PARFLOW_DIR', '/home/raphael/parflow/parflow')
```

Within Tcl, the equivalent thing (to go at the *top* of the script) is:

```
set ::env(PARFLOW_DIR) /home/raphael/parflow/parflow
```

Remember, once you start a process running, it no longer sees any changes to environment variables in its parent process; a child process inherits whatever was defined at the time that the parent process started it.

Comment: Thanks ! That works ! I also used `set env(PARFLOW_DIR) /home/raphael/parflow/parflow`, I guess it's the same as `set ::env(PARFLOW_DIR) /home/raphael/parflow/parflow` ?